# How to include Google Maps JS library locally and not from CDN

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, bower

Currently I am loading the google maps JS API from the google CDN like this in my hybrid mobile app.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Is there a clean, official, way to include this library locally in my resources? I cannot for exmaple find an official bower component, etc...

eg

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Can I just download the JS file from the above URL and include it in the relevant folder in my web app?

Comment: https://libraries.io/bower/google-maps ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.  The [Terms](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?csw=1) state:

> **10.1 Administrative Restrictions.**
>
> No access to APIs or Content except through the Service. You will not access the Maps API(s) or the Content except through the Service.
> For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through
> interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces)
> other than the Maps API(s).
>
> **10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions.**
> No use of Content outside the Service. You will not use any Content outside of the Service
> except as expressly permitted to do so in Subsection (d). For example,
> you will not export or save the Content to a third party’s platform or
> service. No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index,
> or store any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you
> may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of
> improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to
> network latency (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from
> accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage:
>
> - is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days);
> - is secure;
> - does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service; and
> - does not modify attribution in any way.