# Firefox Addon uses Google Maps API, remote scripts and EVAL are NOT allowed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to fix up an old Firefox addon which makes extensive use of the Google Maps API.  However, AMO CSP disallows ALL remote scripts and evals.  AMO CSP compliance required for addon to be signed, only signed addons allowed to be installed and run.

From AMO's validation feedback:

```
Security Tests    0 errors, 6 warnings, 0 notices
    Scripts must not be remote
    Warning: <script> tags must not be referenced to script files that are hosted remotely.
        chrome/content/file.html
        4 <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;key=<...>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is there any way to download, and modify the API into files for use in this environment?  The project has had an API key for many years and used code remotely.  I am just stepping in to help revive the obsolete addon.  Beyond the technical, are there licensing issues with the code usage in this context?  Currently licensed under MPL-1.0 but it could trivially be changed to MPL-2.0, which I am advocating as the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, after further research, the best option is simply not to use Google Maps API, due to all the reasons mentioned above.

- Not open source compatible [[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429805/how-to-include-google-maps-js-library-locally-and-not-from-cdn)]
- Not available for embedded applications
- Not Mozilla Firefox Addons CSP compatible
- EXTREMELY slow to fix SERIOUS security problems (eval-soup)
- Inadequate update frequency or support
- Prohibitively restrictive barriers to access
- Inflexibile, unsuitable, undesireable.

What ever happened to the mantra, "Do no harm?"  Has it become, "Do no good?"  Anyways...

One of the many other free software libraries will achieve what I want.

I could bypass the whole issue entirely, and just present a text list of regions with check boxes for areas of interest, build a combined - possibly non-contiguous - polygon(s), and use any Geo capable polygon lib to check if arbitrary points fall inside or outside the boundaries of a polygon.